# CDX funded vs unfunded returns timeseries

Tags: cds

I've been asked to provide a CDX.NA.IG *unfunded* total returns timeseries, for which I've been able to use a Bloomberg ticker LX01TUUU Index. This works fine - it's called an unfunded total returns index

I also understand the difference between funded and unfunded securities in general

When I look at the unfunded returns timeseries, what exactly is this measuring? Is it the returns for some kind of 'unfunded CDX contract' (as opposed to funded one - a CLN?). Or, is it that the things underlying the CDX are 'filtered' to only included unfunded securities?

Comment: Maybe unfunded is based on cds?

Comment: That’s one of the suggestions I was trying to describe. Does that mean there are two kinds of CDX contract though?

Comment: So, the cdx indices (or index series) are completely standardised. You can read the documents that describe exactly how they work. There's a chance that someone here is familiar with them, but you'll learn more if you read the index specs yourself... (ie I don't know but I'm pretty sure that's where the info is)